# Watson API - Retrieve and Rank - Error uploading JSON

Tags: json, retrieve-and-rank

I'm following the tutorial at [Retrieve and Rank - Get Started](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/get_start.shtml), and I'm at the following step:

> Issue the following command to upload the cranfield_data.json data to the example_collection collection. Replace {username}, {password}, {solr_cluster_id}, and {/path_to_file} with your information:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u "{username}":"{password}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/{solr_cluster_id}/solr/example_collection/update" --data-binary @{/path_to_file}/cranfield_data.json
```

I'm lobbing the request with the correct username and password, and correct cluster_id and path to the json, but I get the following error:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u "username":"password" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/cluster_id/solr/example_collection/update" --data-binary @forum_data/parsed_answers.json

Error: WRRCSH006: Error forwarding request [/solr/example_collection/update] for Solr cluster [sc5b47c5e3_bab3_4aff_a818_f0d786d6dece].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were characters in the JSON causing it be malformed.

Answer (score 0):

Just verify the JSON "parsed_answers.json", to check for all the punctuations i.e. ";","," to be correctly placed and as per the defined schema, and try to re-upload